# Execute `ls` whenever user does a `cd` on terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, bashrc, .bash-profile

I know `bashrc` is executed on terminal startup. But my use case is something like this, 

 
To execute a specific command, say `ls`, whenever user executes another specific command, say `cd`, on the terminal.

My current solution is overriding `cd` command. But again that I feel is not a good solution. But my restriction here is that my user-group may not be aware of this new command that I may create and continue using `cd`.

Comment: Possible, but not a good idea to override commonly-used builtins. Rather create a new function like `cdl`.

Comment: Updated my question a bit. I already have overrided the `cd` command but I am hoping there may be a better solution.

Comment: Either the builtin is overridden and then `cd` can do something else, or it's not overriden and then `cd` is just a regular `cd`. Are you asking how to force other users to use your overridden `cd`?

Comment: So, Yes I think I can take a flag which will decide this enhanced behaviour of `cd`